# Second display not using the correct refresh rate

Tags: display

I have a second display at work, and when i plug it in i use a thunderbolt to vga adapter, however it always uses the wrong refresh rate 90hz instead of 60hz, is there a way to stop this from happening? As its getting annoying when i use my secondary display at work and it moves my windows then the other screen appears blank.

Comment: I suppose you try : System Preferences > Displays > Displays ?

Comment: Upgrading to ML seemed to fix this issue :S